# Calculating Column (weight/max(weight)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
select ema.es_symbol as symbol, ema.score as score, ema.weight as weight, rsi.relative_strength_index as relative_strength_index
from ema_score ema, relative_strength_index rsi inner join
    (select rsi_symbol, max(rsi_date) as maxDate from relative_strength_index group by rsi_symbol) rsiDate
    on rsi.rsi_symbol = rsiDate.rsi_symbol
    and rsi.rsi_date = rsiDate.maxDate
where ema.es_symbol = rsi.rsi_symbol
and ema.score not in (0,1,10,11)
and rsi.relative_strength_index not in (0,100);
```

I am trying to add a calculated column like the one below as the final column:

```
ema.weight/max(ema.weight)
```

The result I want is each symbols weight divided by the max weight in the weight column. When I try it my way, I only receive 1 row of results. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Any aggregate function, such as max(), without a group by clause collapses the resultset into a single record.

Comment: I tried a group by but my calculated column receives the same answer for each row.

Comment: @ULuFlanders that because you have to use subquery as divisor, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use subquery with `MAX` as divisor, something like:

```
select ema.weight*1.0/(select max(weight) from #t ema2)
from #t ema
```

Comment: I adapted this into the query and it does work.  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Any aggregate function, such as max(), without a group by clause collapses the resultset into a single record. You need to select the max value in a subquery and associate it using a cross join with all records. Furthermore do not mix implicit and explicit joins, you can have very nasty surprises if you add an outer join to the query!

```
select ema.es_symbol as symbol, ema.score as score, ema.weight as weight, ema.weight/maxweight as percentage, rsi.relative_strength_index as relative_strength_index
from ema_score ema
     join (select max(weight) as maxweight from ema_score) t
     inner join relative_strength_index rsi on ema.es_symbol = rsi.rsi_symbol
     inner join
    (select rsi_symbol, max(rsi_date) as maxDate from relative_strength_index group by rsi_symbol) rsiDate
    on rsi.rsi_symbol = rsiDate.rsi_symbol
    and rsi.rsi_date = rsiDate.maxDate
where ema.score not in (0,1,10,11)
and rsi.relative_strength_index not in (0,100);
```

Comment: I like this solution better but it does not filter out weights that are filtered out by the Where and And clause below.  Sorry if  my question did not reflect that clearer.

Comment: Then in the subquery you have to add the same where criteria, including any joins unfortunately.